# Iterate through container of structs by specific member

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a function

```
template<typename I> double mean(I begin, I end)
{
    double s = 0;
    size_t n = 0;
    while(begin != end)
    {
        s += *begin++;
        ++n;
    }
    
    return s / n;
}
```

and a vector of structs T:

```
struct T
{
    double a;
    double b;
};
vector<T> v;
```

Is there an elegant way to compute mean of all `a` members of structs in `v`? Some way to wrap `vector<T>::iterator` to iterator that extracts `a` member?

Comment: [`boost::transform_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) and [`std::ranges::views::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view) with C++20 range.

Comment: Just FYI, your `mean()` function is technically returning an average, so I would have named it `average()` instead.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to tell `mean()` which member of `T` to look at.  You can use a [pointer-to-data-member](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_data_members) for that, eg:

```cpp
template<typename Iter, typename T>
double mean(Iter begin, Iter end, double (T::*member))
{
    double s = 0;
    size_t n = 0;
    while (begin != end)
    {
        s += (*begin++).*member;
        ++n;
    }
    
    return s / n;
}

struct T
{
    double a;
    double b;
};

vector<T> v;
// fill v...
double m = mean(v.begin(), v.end(), &T::a/*or b*/);
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/43sUFl)

You could take this further by getting rid of your manual loop and use [`std::accumulate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <numeric>
 
template<typename Iter, typename T>
double mean(Iter begin, Iter end, double (T::*member))
{
    size_t n = 0;
    double s = std::accumulate(begin, end, 0.0,
        [&](double acc, const T &t){ ++n; return acc + t.*member; }
    );
    return s / n;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/bzaS1w)

In which case, you could just get rid of `mean()` altogether:

```cpp
#include <numeric>

vector<T> v;
// fill v...
double m = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0,
    [](double acc, const T &t){ return acc + t.a/*or b*/; }
) / v.size();
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/vZGQJp)

Comment: Looks great. Thank you very much!